# itextpdf v8.0.0 bold text doesn't look same as that of v5.5.13.2 even same font name & size is used. Perticularly for small bold font sizes

Tags: java, itext

We were already using itextpdf v5.5.13.2 due to vulnerability
we have migrated to v8.0.0. Now after migrating to v8.0.0, even if we use same bold font with same size, the text looks stretched vertically, also character spacing reduced in v8. For small font sizes v8 text looks blurry.Image comparison attached.

Sample program in v5.5.13.2

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Helvetica", 8, Font.BOLD);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Transaction Details for ", font);
document.add(paragraph);
```

Sample in v8.0.0

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("Helvetica");
Style style = new Style();
style.setBold();
style.setFontSize(8);
style.setFont(font);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Transaction Details for").addStyle(style);
document.add(paragraph);
```

`

I tried with setting characterSpacing in v8. But unable to reduce vertical stretching of the font in v8. Also it looks like bold thickness in v8 is different than that of v5. For small size fonts its a issue.
Also we can't change the font size in v8 and make it bigger.
Kindly advice.

Here is the image that shows the behaviour under small sizes.

[image: comparison-sample]

Bold thickness comparison -

[image: Bold-thickness]

Comment: Found the cause. After creating font using PdfFontFactory.createFont("Helvetica-Bold", PdfEncodings.WINANSI, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED) the font now look same. SetBold() seems different than directly creating bold font